# PHP - false == 0 but false != "00"

Tags: php, boolean-expression

I had a problem with checking falsy conditions and don't understand how 'false' works.

I tested the code above,

```
echo (0 == false); //->true
echo ("0" == false); //->true
echo ("0" == 0); //->true
echo ("000000000000" == 0); //->true
echo ("000000000000" == false); //->false
```

And don't understand why the last result is false instead of true.

Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Have you gone through https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php yet?

Answer (score 0):

"000000000000" and "00" and indeed anything other than "0" are evaluated as true because they are treated as regular non-empty strings in PHP and therefore not considered as a falsy value. PHP will only evaluate "0" as false.